# Obliquity and projected surface area

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Consider the Earth-Moon system in the inertial reference frame $(X,Y,Z)$. Let's also consider a non-planar orbit with an inclination angle $i$. How does one find the obliquity and the projected surface area of the moon onto the plane that encompasses the Earth-Moon orbit with respect to the inclination angle $i$?

I've seen the formula: $ A = \pi r^2 \cos(i)$ for the completely spherical case but it seems too straightforward.

Also, considering the moon to be completely spherical, its projection onto the plane will always be a circumference? A direct projection would give us a $4 \pi R^2$ given that $R$ is the radius of the moon, but at the semi-major and semi-minor axis, it would be different.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "a non-planar orbit with an inclination angle "? And what kind of projection are you considering?

Comment: I added the image for more clarity, hopefully it's enough.

Comment: OK. But it is still not clear what kind of projection you have in mind. If you project a sphere ***perpendicularly*** on a plane, you get a circle. If the projection is not perpendicular you get an ellipse.

Comment: It isn't clear.  Possibly you are thinking of the shadow of the Moon cast upon the Earth during a solar eclipse.  But this depends on the position of the Sun as well.